# Set as People Album Thumbnail does not work in Picasa

Tags: picasa, face-recognition

Sometime Picasa shows random images as people album thumbnail. This case it is impossible to change.

[image]

How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seen that if you right click the thumbnail and refresh the thumbnail, then right click on the image that you want an click to set as google thumbnail, and then right click on the image that you want to and click set as people album thumbnail.

This would help you to resolve the issue.